# Text vertical shift due to fractional heights in IE 9 and 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Consider the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15px">First line</p>
<p style="height: 24px; line-height: 24px; background: green; color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px">Test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

IE 9/10 display it as expected:

[image]

However, let us add another line to the first paragraph.

```
<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15px">First line<br />Second line</p>
```

After this the "Test" paragraph gets shifted relative to its background:

[image]

Under a closer look it's quite noticeable.

[image]

I believe the reason for this is that height of the first paragraph is fractional (as shown by IE dev tools):

[image]

Now, I have a web page with a lot of such text blocks, some of them shifted and some of them not. Naturally, I want all blocks to appear normal and not shifted. Is it possible to force IE 9/10 to render it that way?

[image]

By the way, versions 7 and 8 of IE display the page just fine.

Comment: Microsoft says the behavior is "by design": https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/789602/text-vertical-shift-due-to-fractional-heights.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the text in a `span` and set the `vertical-align` to `middle`

```
<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15px">First line<br />Second line</p>
<p style="height: 24px; line-height: 24px; background: green; color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px">
    <span style="vertical-align:middle">Test</span>
</p>
```

[jsfiddle Result](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/uAAjU/3/show/) ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/uAAjU/3/))

This fixes IE 9/10 however, it will shift the span below the middle in Chrome/Firefox.

Also, inline styles are frowned upon, but I'm assuming you're using them to summarize your point.

Comment: Although the "Test" text does change its position in IE 9/10 by 1 pixel, it's still positioned differently when the first paragraph contains one line and when it contains two lines. But thanks for the idea!

And, you're right, I'm using inline styles just to make a point.

Comment: Curious why IE 7 and 8 don't suffer from this.  The issue smells like a possible bug...have you considered submitting a bug report?  This bug sounds like it's in the ballpark of what you're experiencing: [IE9+'s mishandles vertical placement of glyphs for certain fonts](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/680730/ie9-s-mishandles-vertical-placement-of-glyphs-for-certain-fonts)

Comment: I don't think it's that bug. I've just submitted a bug report: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/789602/text-vertical-shift-due-to-fractional-heights.